# Unable to programmatically edit text after implementing fragments

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

Heres the background info.

Used this code to edit Text and Image with some custom attributes (custom fonts, images, etc)

```
//Font Loader
    Typeface ralewayFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/raleway.ttf");
    Typeface abeatFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/abeat.otf");

    TextView hiText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
    TextView welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    TextView chancechatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chancechat);

    hiText.setTypeface(ralewayFont);
    welcomeText.setTypeface(ralewayFont);
    chancechatText.setTypeface(abeatFont);
```

Thats a small excerpt. It was placed under the onCreate method of main activity.

Now I have implemented fragments as such. Where do I implement the code. (I've tried the old code and in the WelcomePage method. Here the new code. Any ideas? Also to note i had move my editTexts from activity_main.xml to fragment_main_dummy.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  
        switch (position) {  
        case 0:  
            return fragment = new WelcomePage();  
        case 1:  
            return fragment = new Facebook();   
        default:  
            break;  
        }  
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public static class WelcomePage extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class Facebook extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_main_two, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am making incorrect assumptions because I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

I recommend setting up your TextViews inside of your onActivityCreated() method since you do not have access to your root view inside of a fragment's onCreate(). Modify your WelcomePage fragment to look like this:

Updated with changes to pass a reference of the application context to WelcomePage.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Context appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  
        switch (position) {  
        case 0:  
            return fragment = new WelcomePage(appContext);  
        case 1:  
            return fragment = new Facebook();   
        default:  
            break;  
        }  
        return fragment;
    }
}


public static class WelcomePage extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private Context context;

    public WelcomePage(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_two, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Typeface ralewayFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/raleway.ttf");
        Typeface abeatFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/abeat.otf");

        TextView hiText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hi);
        TextView welcomeText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        TextView chancechatText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chancechat);

        hiText.setTypeface(ralewayFont);
        welcomeText.setTypeface(ralewayFont);
        chancechatText.setTypeface(abeatFont);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't able to getAssets becasue the WelcomePage is a static class. Any ideas? And i believe what you are assuming is correct.

Comment: I updated my answer with a few changes. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it should work. Basically since your WelcomePage class does not extend Activity and it is static, you do not have direct access to the application context. So we need to save a reference to it in the main activity, and then pass it along when a WelcomePage fragment is instantiated.

Comment: View onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
So this line throws an error in Eclipse. It says "The return type is incompatible with Fragment.onActivityCreated(Bundle)"

Any ideas? thanks for the help so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yup, simple mistake. Change it to public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState).